# Facebook apps $data["user_id"] is empty on mobile devices

Tags: facebook

I have created a app that works fine  - but not on mobile devices.
After the user logged into my app I'm caught in a loop and $data["user_id"] seems empty. Here's the code snipplet I'm using:

```
    $canvas_page = 'https://m.facebook.com/apps/'.$app_id;

 $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
   . "&scope=user_birthday";

    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), 
    true);

  if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
    }
```

Anyone got an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain that the `signed_request` is POSTed to Mobile apps, it is not listed in the types of app that receive it:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/
However, as per that documentation, your if statement should probably be looking for the presence of `$_REQUEST` itself and not specifically the `user_id`.